# PublisherAdView resize not happening on Android 9 devices when PublisherAdView.setAdSize

Tags: java, android, admob, google-dfp

On All android devices except on Android 9 after the AD is loaded I was able to change the width of the PublisherAdView to go fullscreen width by doing the following

publisherAdView is the object of the PublisherAdView

```
int width = Util.getDisplayWidthInDp(publisherAdView.getContext());
publisherAdView.setAdSizes(new AdSize(width,80));
```

above code will resize the publisherAdView to fit full width but on Android pie devices publisherAdView is not resizing.

I also tried

```
width =-1
```

It might work but DFP is throwing an error saying "-1x80" is too small to flight.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?